# jQuery Slideshow Breaks when I add buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slideshow

I've been trying to create a slideshow that can be changed with radio (or practically, any kind) buttons. I've already gotten the slideshow itself to work, which can be seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Chiefwiggy/xycs1aLs/3/), however, when I try to add buttons to the equation, the whole thing breaks. Right now all it is showing me is the final picture, then it fades to the penultimate picture. Here is the function that I am currently employing.

```
    $(function () {
    "use strict";
    setInterval(function(){rotateImages()}, 4000);

    var pic1 = $('#slideshow div:first');
    var pic2 = $('#slideshow div:nth-child(2)');
    var pic3 = $('#slideshow div:nth-child(3)');
    var pic4 = $('#slideshow div:nth-child(4)');
    var pic5 = $('#slideshow div:last');

    $("#choosePic1").click(rotateImages(pic1));
    $("#choosePic2").click(rotateImages(pic2));
    $("#choosePic3").click(rotateImages(pic3));
    $("#choosePic4").click(rotateImages(pic4));
    $("#choosePic5").click(rotateImages(pic5)); 

});

function rotateImages(manualChange) {


    var CurrentPhoto = $('#slideshow .current');
   if (manualChange !== null) {
        CurrentPhoto = manualChange;   
    }
    var NextPhoto = CurrentPhoto.next();
    if (NextPhoto.length === 0) {
        NextPhoto = $('#slideshow div:first');
    }
    CurrentPhoto.removeClass('current').addClass('previous');
    NextPhoto.css({
        opacity: 0.0
    }).addClass('current')
        .animate({
        opacity: 1.0
    }, 1000,

    function () {
        CurrentPhoto.removeClass('previous');
    });
}
```

I've left the CSS and HTML accompaniments on JSFiddle, which can be seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Chiefwiggy/hanfuv7d/).

Why when I add buttons does the whole function break?

Comment: You should really `clearInterval` when the `click` interrupts auto play and then give the user an option to start auto play if need be. It'd be a sloppy carousel otherwise!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your idea is to show the corresponding image to based on the click. What you were doing is, setting the manual selection to the current image whereas you should've set it to the next image as that's what's going to be shown as per your *logic*.

You could also replace `setInterval` with `setTimeout` which ensures that the animation is always complete before the next queue starts.

To check if a param is passed to a function, you could simpy do `if (param)` as opposed to `if (param !== null)`

You must also check for the existense of the element via `.length` even if it's not necessary in your case as you have proper mapping between images and buttons.

*The most important bits are:*

**User experience:** Whenever you need to interrupt an auto played animation based on set interval, clear the interval. If you don't, it's going to be a bad experience as the auto play will keep going even if one doesn't want it as the whole point of manual intervention is to see that specific image!

**Code Optimization**: Jquery/JavaScript provides ways to minimize your code thru various in-built methods. Make use of them which reduces the lines of code you write and makes it easier to manage in the future. I've done the `click` bit as a demo. I am sure there is more just in this very snippet.

Take a look at the amended code below.

```js
$(function () {
    "use strict";
    var timer = setInterval(rotateImages, 2000);
    
    $(".buttons").on("click", ".slideshowSelect", function() {
        
        clearInterval(timer);
        var photoIndex = parseInt($(this).val(), 10) - 1;
        rotateImages( $('#slideshow div').eq(photoIndex) );
        
        //Give an option to the user thru a button to resume auto play
        //or resume auto play after a set amount of time
        setTimeout(function() {
            timer = setInterval(rotateImages, 2000);
        }, 5000);
    });
    
    function rotateImages(manualChange) {

        var CurrentPhoto = $('#slideshow .current');
        var NextPhoto = CurrentPhoto.next();
        
        if (manualChange && manualChange.length) {
            NextPhoto = manualChange;
        }
        if (NextPhoto.length === 0) {
            NextPhoto = $('#slideshow div:first');
        }
        CurrentPhoto.removeClass('current').addClass('previous');
        NextPhoto.css({
            opacity: 0.0
        }).addClass('current')
        .animate({
            opacity: 1.0
        }, 1000, function () {
            CurrentPhoto.removeClass('previous');
        });
    }
});
```

```css
#slideshow div {
    z-index: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
#slideshow div.previous {
    z-index: 1;
}
#slideshow div.current {
    z-index: 2;
}
.slideshowSelect {
   height:22px;
    width: 22px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slideshow">

    <span class="buttons">
        <input type="button" class="slideshowSelect" value="1" />
        <input type="button" class="slideshowSelect" value="2" />
        <input type="button" class="slideshowSelect"value="3" />
        <input type="button" class="slideshowSelect" value="4" />
        <input type="button" class="slideshowSelect" value="5" />
    </span>

    <div class="current">
        <img src="http://www.butterfly-tattoo-design.com/butterfly-tattoos-6926.jpg" alt="Img" width="300" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="http://www.serendipitystamps.com/mm5/pics/stamps/1255FloralButterflyStamp.gif" alt="Img" width="300" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="http://images.clipartpanda.com/free-butterfly-clipart-RcGjaR7cL.jpeg" alt="Img" width="300" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="http://www.cgvector.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/Vector_Butterfly_000018.jpg" alt="Img" width="300" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="http://www.weddingchaos.co.uk/images-content/animals/butterfly.jpg" alt="Img" width="300" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a good answer. I'll just add for your future reference that if an argument to a function is not supplied in JavaScript, its value is undefined, not null. However, the answerer's suggestion to simply use `if (param)` as a check for an undefined value is solid as long as there's no chance that `param` has an existing but falsy value such as 0 or an empty string--a quite safe assumption in this snippet.

Comment: I've just started to have a problem with this model as I've moved on to other parts of the design. I've noticed that the rotation starts to speed up from one rotation every 2 seconds, to seemingly 3 rotations per second. Is there a quick-fix to this problem?

Comment: There may be issues with the _other parts of the design_ that you mentioned. I am not sure though as the demo works well given the context of your question. If there are other issues, please ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

1. Because your `$("#choosePic1").click(rotateImages(pic1));` will call the rotated images imediately with that `pic1`, you have to use `.bind` to create a new function for the `click` event to call with give param.
2. `if (manualChange !== null)` will only be true when `manualChange` change is null, if you don't give value to `manualChange` and left `undefined`, the if test will become false and then CurrentPhoto will assigned with `undefined`.
3. In your logic, what you should assign in `CurrentPhoto = manualChange;` should be `NextPhoto = manualChange;` as your intents seems to change the user selected picture.
4. add a `.stop(true, true)` to make the animation jump directly to the last that should be played.
5. `:nth-child(2)` will match to the 2th children in `#sildeshow` however, in your `#slideshow`, the first element is a `<span>`, so `$('#slideshow div:first')` will select to same item with `$('#slideshow div:nth-of-type(2)')`, and so to others. You should use `:nth-of-type(2)` to select the 2nd div in `#slideshow`, so to others.
6. You can further use setTimeout instead of setInterval, then its easier to cancel the next auto Rotate, prevent it overlaps with manually played animation, and setTimeout at the end of `rotateImages` to make it restart the autoplay.

```js
$(function () {
    "use strict";
    setInterval(function () {
        rotateImages()
    }, 4000);

    var pic1 = $('#slideshow div:first');
    var pic2 = $('#slideshow div:nth-of-type(2)');
    var pic3 = $('#slideshow div:nth-of-type(3)');
    var pic4 = $('#slideshow div:nth-of-type(4)');
    var pic5 = $('#slideshow div:last');
    
    // use .bind to create new function which when executed, will execute rotateImages and pass picX as its param.
    $("#choosePic1").click(rotateImages.bind(null, pic1));
    $("#choosePic2").click(rotateImages.bind(null, pic2));
    $("#choosePic3").click(rotateImages.bind(null, pic3));
    $("#choosePic4").click(rotateImages.bind(null, pic4));
    $("#choosePic5").click(rotateImages.bind(null, pic5));

});

function rotateImages(manualChange) {
 

    var CurrentPhoto = $('#slideshow .current');
    var NextPhoto;
    // Use != null to test undefined and null
    if (manualChange != null) {
        // Assign it to NextPhoto
        NextPhoto = manualChange;
    } else {
        NextPhoto = CurrentPhoto.next();
    }
    if (NextPhoto.length === 0) {
        NextPhoto = $('#slideshow div:first');
    }
    CurrentPhoto.removeClass('current').addClass('previous');
    // Use .stop to skip current playing (if caused by autoRotate) and start the newest.
    NextPhoto.stop(true, true).css({
        opacity: 0.0
    }).addClass('current')
        .animate({
        opacity: 1.0
    }, 1000,

    function () {
        CurrentPhoto.removeClass('previous');
    });
}
```

```css
#slideshow div {
    z-index: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
#slideshow div.previous {
    z-index: 1;
}
#slideshow div.current {
    z-index: 2;
}
.slideshowSelect {
   height:22px;
    width: 22px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slideshow"> <span class="buttons">
                 <input type="button" id="choosePic1" class="slideshowSelect" value="1">
                <input type="button" id="choosePic2" class="slideshowSelect" value="2">
                <input type="button" id="choosePic3" class="slideshowSelect"value="3" >
                <input type="button" id="choosePic4" class="slideshowSelect" value="4">
                <input type="button" id="choosePic5" class="slideshowSelect" value="5">
                </span> 
    <div class="current">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/abstract/" alt="Img" height="382" width="594">
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/people/" alt="Img" height="382" width="594">
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/" alt="Img" height="382" width="594">
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/animals/" alt="Img" height="382" width="594">
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/nature/" alt="Img" height="382" width="594">
    </div>
</div>
```